# Signer not valid error

Tags: iphone, xcode, itunes, app-store-connect, adhoc

I've created an ad hoc build of my app and would like another person to install it.  I have their device ID (two actually) in the provisioning profile.  My certificate is the same for ad hoc and app store provisioning.  The certificate is valid in keychain.  I've selected the ad hoc profile in Xcode for this build, which is linked to the distribution certificate.

I send the user the provisioning file and .app file.  They drop both into iTunes and sync then get this error on both devices:

```
The application "myapp" was not installed on the iPhone "user's iPhone" because the signer is not valid.
```

I've removed all profiles from my iPhone, dropped the above two files into iTunes, sync'd and installed the app successfully. I can't get it to repro for me.  I need to repro this problem locally to figure out the issue.  Any ideas how that can be done?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Did you add Entitlements?  Put the signing at the Target level, not the Project level?  Select the Ad Hoc profile?  DO a clean prior to the build?  Select the Ad Hoc Device foe the build?

The best bet is to follow Apple's documentation *exactly*, get your build settings to *exactly* match Apple's.

Comment: Not setting it on the Target was the issue.  What is the difference with that setting and the project setting for ad hoc?

Comment: Also, why is it I never saw the user's behavior when I sync'd the ad hoc?

Comment: Where is Apple's documentation for this? It's very hard to find the right place that explains the entire process from start to finish (it's not in the provisioning portal)

Comment: **Manually creating and adding entitlements is no longer necessary**; this is a question and answer from 2009. These days, entitlements are a part of the provisioning profile, and Xcode takes them from there.

Answer (score 6):

It's a good idea to check the imbedded.mobileprovision file that comes bundled in the .app file to make sure that the UID is in there. Just do the following:

1. unzip ProblemApp.ipa
2. cd Payload/ProblemApp.app
3. pico imbedded.mobileprovision

Look for the UID of your device within this file. If it's not there then it's probably not added to the provisioning file within the portal.

Answer (score 4):

From the docs:

> Building an app for Ad Hoc
>   distribution is similar to building an
>   app for App Store distribution, with
>   an exception of two additional steps.
>   First, you need to create an Ad Hoc
>   Distribution Provisioning profile and
>   add the UDIDs of the iOS devices that
>   you want to distribute to using the
>   iPhone Developer Program Provisioning
>   Portal. Second, you need to create a
>   code-signing Entitlements file. For
>   information about how to create an
>   Entitlements file read the Managing
>   Application Entitlements section of
>   the iOS Development Guide.

---

> Managing Application Entitlements
>
> iOS provides access to special
>   resources and capabilities—such as
>   whether your application can be
>   debugged—through properties called
>   entitlements. To specify entitlement
>   information in your application, you
>   add an entitlement property-list file
>   containing entitlement definitions
>   (key/value pairs) to your project.
>   When you build your application, Xcode
>   copies the file to the generated
>   application bundle.
>
> To add an entitlements property-list
>   file to your project:
>
> In the Groups & Files list, select the
>   Resources group. Choose File > New
>   File. Choose the iOS > Code Signing >
>   Entitlements template. Name the file
>   Entitlements.plist. (You can use any
>   name; just ensure it matches the value
>   of the Code Signing Entitlements build
>   setting, as explained later in this
>   section.) Set the type of the
>   property-list file to iPhone
>   Entitlements. With the file selected
>   in the text editor, choose View >
>   Property List Type > iPhone
>   Entitlements plist.
>
> Add your entitlement entries to the
>   file. For each entitlement property
>   you need to define:
>
> Click the Add Child or Add Sibling
>   buttons to the right of the selected
>   row. The Add Child button has three
>   lines depicting a hierarchy, the Add
>   Sibling button has a plus (+) sign on
>   it. Choose the entitlement property
>   from the pop-up menu that appears. If
>   the entitlement you need to add
>   doesn’t appear in the menu, choose
>   View > Property List Type > Default
>   for File Type. Then enter the
>   entitlement-key name and type.
>
> Enter the value for the property. Set
>   the Code Signing Entitlements build
>   setting for the target to the name of
>   the newly added entitlements
>   property-list file.

---

> Once you
>   have created your Entitlements file
>   and added it to your Code Signing
>   Entitlements build setting, open the
>   Entitlements file and add or edit the
>   get-task-allow key and set it to
>   false.
>
> In addition to compressing your .app
>   bundle to distribute your Ad Hoc build
>   to testers, etc. it is recommended
>   that you also compress the
>   provisioning profile before
>   distributing because certain email
>   clients and servers may corrupt the
>   provisioning profile.
>
> For information about Ad Hoc
>   distribution please read the
>   Publishing Applications for Testing
>   section in the iOS Development Guide.

Comment: This is great answer, get-task-allow key is the main hurdle for most people.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem recently with one tester on a recent build. It turned out that my tester had reset their iPod Touch and removed the provisioning profile in the process.

Just something to consider.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error by doing something dumber than anyone else has posted. I added new devices to the profile, but forgot to download the updated version, add it to Xcode, and point the project to it. When I set it up properly, testers were able to install the app fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another fun one.... if you have separate entitlement files for iphone and ipad, make sure you set the target for the file for each specific build...otherwise it won't show in the build and you'll get this error

Answer (score 1):

I arrived here because I had the same problem as the OP. It indeed turned out that I didn't have the UDID in the entitlements file, even though I'm sure I used refresh in the XCode organizer. Another refresh made no difference.

In the end I removed all provisioning profiles and *then* did a refresh. Things now work.

I have no idea whether this is a glitch in my setup, or an operator error. But just in case anyone else finds themselves in this situation: it may pay to remove your provisioning profiles and then do a refresh.

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't work for me with an iphone 3G running IOS 3.1.3.  I verified that the distribution profile wasn't on the phone by looking at settings->general ( there was no profile option listed).

I then installed the iphone config utility:

http://support.apple.com/kb/DL851

Then:

1. run iphone config
2. drag and drop embedded.mobileprovision file to app
3. click device on left side
4. click "provisioning profiles" tab
5. click on the profile and then click the "install" button

Then the app installed just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as the OP too.  Dumb mistake:  I accidentally dropped the last two digits off the device I was attempting to ad hoc distribute to when I registered it as a device.

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem two times ( `xcode 4.2 ios 5`)

1st,time i forgot to add armv6 in architecture

2nd, time i have created to many provisioning files with same developer id that i should delete others key-chain according to use of bundle identifier ...and i mistakenly deleted valid and used other kechain