# iPhone: Application Install Fails With "Invalid Signer" Error

Tags: iphone, installation, adhoc

The iPhone is attached to a Mac runnning the latest iTunes version and I am 100% sure that her UDID is in the provisioning file.  Her iPhone has not been jailbroken and we even restored it to factory settings.

I am having trouble installing our development build on this one iPhone.  The error is:

> the application "[Application Name]" was not
>   installed on the iPhone "iPhone"
>   because the signer is not valid

I am 100% sure that the UDID is accurately entered in the provisioning file and that they correctly copied the right provision file/build combo.  This same combo has been successfully installed on over a dozen iphones.

We have been able to install this on some devices with no problems.

Edit:

From comments to an answer:

> We can install it on 100 iphone with
>   our account. We have about 40 iphones
>   in this provisioning profile and it
>   works on 38 of them.

Comment: What is the sequence of install failures? Did you install on 38 devices and then it failed in sequence on the next two? Or did you install some successfully, then a failure then more successes?

Answer (score 3):

I had a fix that seemed to work for one user who was having troubles:

1. remove all offending profiles and apps
2. restart
3. add back provisioning profile FIRST
4. sync device
5. now add app resource
6. sync again to get app on device

the offending machine was a windows box... dunno if that makes a difference.

If someone else gets this issue - try this and let us know if this is the actual fix or workaround!  This goblin has rarely been seen and solved with the same steps.

this was my reference for the fix idea:

http://iphone.forums.wordpress.org/topic/installing-beta#post-1194

Comment: This solved the issue for me - it is also described here: https://devforums.apple.com/message/276242

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769049/ad-hoc-distribution-odyssey-not-valid-signer

Answer (score 2):

Does the answer to this question help you at all?

[Signer not valid error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857414/signer-not-valid-error)

> Put the signing at the Target level, not the Project level

I'm personally not sure what that means but it worked in that case

Answer (score 1):

(Ignore: I misread the question and didn't notice he had dozens of installs already so my advice does not apply)

If you have just the standard developers account, you can only install on up to five phones before the certificate becomes invalid for further installs. If you've already installed it on five phones that is most likely the problem.

Tell Buzz some random guy on the internet said, "Hi!"

Comment: Where do you get that number (five) from? The Developer Account allows you to install Adhoc Distributed applictions on up to 100 registered devices.

Comment: I pretty sure it used to restrict to just 5. It was the big difference between the standard and enterprise accounts. I haven't looked at it recently however.

Comment: The iOS developer program has always been limited to 100 devices.

Answer (score 1):

We can install it on 100 iphone with our account.  We have about 40 iphones in this provisioning profile and it works on 38 of them.  Any other ideas?

I'll tell Buzz that you say hi and if you can help us we'll get you a moon rock!

Comment: Yeah I just noticed while editing that you had over a dozen installs. What do the two phones that don't work have in common e.g. model, system version, installed apps etc.

Comment: You should not use the answers section for clarifications or additions to your question. Use the comment section instead and/or edit the original question.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to try:

1. Renew the profile at the Developer's portal. It may have expired or become corrupt.
2. Create [a new provisioning profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074546/the-executable-was-signed-with-invalid-entitlements/1075213#1075213)

Comment: +1 I had an issue like this and a new provisioning profile helped fix it

Answer (score 0):

Does the mobileprovision file show up on the device after sync? You should see it in

```
Settings->General->Profiles
```

If it doesn't then that would be the problem. Check once again that the UDID is correct - same UDID on iTunes and in the developer portal. Try syncing iTunes with the mobileprovision without trying to install the app. If it still doesn't get installed then CHECK THE UDID. If it is getting installed on all other devices, UDID is most likely the issue.

Comment: The provisioning file is getting installed

Comment: Ok. Do you have an entitlements file in your app (a .plist with just one checkbox). Make sure that for an adhoc build, the check mark is unchecked. Also what is the OS version on the device and the SDK version with which you are compiling the app?

Comment: I have it running on my iphone and a few dozen others with a valid entitlements file (unchecked).  Today I just created a new provisioning file with just their ID's and a new name.  I sent it to them to see if that might work.  They have the most up to date itunes software and iphone software.  We checked.  x-code is ver 3.1.4.  Any other ideas?  I'll let you know what happens when they try to install the build with the new provisioning file (new name and just with their ID's).  THANKS!!!

Comment: Probably not important but the latest Xcode version is 3.2.1. You could try updating on the off chance that fixes something.

Answer (score 0):

If the distribution signing certificate was revoked in the meantime and recreated, you need to remove the old provisioning profile from the device first. This is on an iOS 3.1.3 device.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me recently and I resolved it. Situation was that I had an ad hoc provisioning profile I was using successfully for around 40 devices with several different apps. When a new device was required I would add it to the profile, download, then use 'share' from XCode with the same archived app but the new profile.

Recently my distribution certificate expired, so I created a new one and recreated the provisioning profiles.  Subsequently,  I could still install on the existing devices but would get an error trying to install on new devices, even though I had added them to the profile and installed the profile on the device.

The secret was that although I had created the new distribution cert and added it to my KeyChain, there was still a copy of the old cert in the KeyChain, and that was being used to sign the app.  It turns out that if you do not delete the old provisioning profiles from XCode, when  you start up XCode it will recreate the old cert in the KeyChain, and that will be used to sign the app, which means that the new profile with the new device (created with the new cert) will not match.

Solution: when  you renew  your cert, delete all the old profiles signed with that cert, delete the old cert, then recreate, download and install the new profiles.

hth