# Ad-hoc distribution odyssey - not valid signer

Tags: iphone, sdk, distribution, adhoc

I am totally aware of billions how to and forum discussions out there about this issue. Because I could not find the solution I'm writing here.

Typical situation: I want a co-worker to test my App. I thought on Ad-Hoc distribution. I followed every kind of tutorials. But I receive always a "valid signer" issue in iTunes.

Basically:

1)  have a distribution certification which works like a charm to upload apps to iTunes;
2)  add UUID number of my friend's iPhone in the portal
3)  use the same App ID I used till now for the AppStore xxxxxx.* so that in the Bundle Identifier I can insert, like always for the appstore, com.mydomain.nameoftheapp
4)  create a provisioning file, Distribution, where I check my and my friend's iPhone
5)  add it to xCode, dragging it to icon in the dock
6)  create the Entitlements.plist and uncheck the only field in it
6)  create a copy of Release, named Distribution and set it active
7)  leave untouched the parameters in the PROJECT
8)  in the TARGET, add the Entitlements.plist in Code Signing Entitlements and the provisioning file (which is present and black, not gray) under Any OS Device, leaving blank Code Signing Identity
9) Add an icon, like always, PNG 57x57

Now, I clean all the targets and then I build. Drag both the mobile provisioning file and the .app to iTunes. Rather than to send it to my friend, I try with my iPhone. But the error is always the same. Can't install because of not valid signer...

Can you help me? I can provide you with screenshots and everything it may help...

Thank you so much!
Fabio

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the process described in this [post](https://devforums.apple.com/message/276242) from the Apple developer forums solved it for me:

1. Remove any versions of the
   application from iTunes.
2. Drag the mobile provision file to iTunes (it seems like nothing happened but continue on)
3. Sync the iPhone (again nothing should appear any different)
4. Drag the app to iTunes
5. Sync the iPhone a second time.

Good luck!