# How can I install iPad Apps on multiple iPads?

Tags: ipad, installation, distribution, adhoc

I have developed an iPad app, and made a distribution provision profile for appstore, I need to install my developed app on 30 iPads for an event, but I couldn't install it. I have en error message which is: (The app "xxxx" was not installed on the iPad "My iPad name" because the signer is not valid).

How can I solve this problem and install my app on the number of iPads I want?

Answer (score 4):

You need to create an ad hoc distribution profile. Add the UDID's of the 30 iPads as test devices in the developer portal, and then include them in the ad hoc distribution profile. Then build for ad hoc distribution. You should then be able to install the app on any of those 30 devices.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen for a number of reasons. I will suggest: review the build creation process step by step.

Here are 2 stackoverflow questions which might help you:

[Signer not valid error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857414/signer-not-valid-error) and [iPhone: Application Install Fails With “Invalid Signer” Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345624/iphone-application-install-fails-with-invalid-signer-error)

The easiest way to give a build to multiple beta testers is to create a "beta" build and distribute it over internet. This (which I use) tool can help you with that:

http://www.hanchorllc.com/betabuilder-for-ios/

[This article](http://kenyarmosh.com/blog/three-ways-to-do-over-the-air-wireless-ad-hoc-ios-beta-programs/) gives information about 2 more similar tools.