# signer not valid error

Tags: iphone, app-store

I build for appstore distribution , but when trying to test it on device (not the developing )

it give the following warning

The application "myapp" was not installed on the iPhone "user's iPhone" because the signer is not valid.

any suggestion to solve that

best regards

Comment: you can refer to @PARTH's answer. I think that would help you.

Answer (score 3):

When you want to test a production version of your app (rather than a developer version) you can't use the App Store provisioning profile and install it on your app.

In XCode > Organizer > Provisioning Profiles you'll see your downloaded provisioning profiles. If you select your App Store provisioning profile you'll see the following:

[image]

*Note the "cannot be installed on devices" clue.*

You need to create an Ad Hoc Distribution provisioning profile and use that to sign your app.  Make sure you add the device(s) to this provisioning profile and include the .mobileprovision file along with the .ipa file when sending it to someone else to test.

Create the Ad Hoc provisioning profile on the iOS Provisioning Portal: http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/provisioningprofiles/viewDistributionProfiles.action

For more info on Ad Hoc distribution see http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/distribution/distribution.action for more information.

Answer (score 2):

The distribution profile which you are using in Code Signing does **not** match the your app's bundle ID.

To get rid of this issue,

Try putting a proper Distribution Profile

or

Delete the existing distribution profile which you are using. Go to Developer Portal on Apple's site and add your app's bundle ID to your Distribution Profile, then download the Distribution Profile and install it in your keychain access.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

This has already been addressed: [Signer not valid error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857414/signer-not-valid-error)

Comment: it's not add hoc , it's app store build

Comment: I would disagree that the linked question/answer resolves this issue. That accepted answer is more or less RTFM. Not helpful. This question and error is very specific to a particular situation of misuse of the App Store provisioning profile. I got this error too and outlined the answer here to help others. Hopefully you got this working awhile ago @Ali and please accept my answer for others to learn from.