# The application <myapp> was not installed on the iPhone "user's iPhone" because the signer is not valid

Tags: iphone

I am a newbie on StackOverflow.

While trying to get Ad-Hoc version and trying to install it on my device I am getting.

`The application "myapp" was not installed on the iPhone "user's iPhone" because the signer is not valid.`

What can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow..!

Checkout my answer in the following link. May be that would help.

[signer not valid error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489471/signer-not-valid-error/5490085#5490085)

If you have any doubts you can just leave a comment below.