# How to Make a build for ios3.1.3 through Xcode 4....?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm using xcode 4 and making the build for ios4 and ios3.1.3 . I'm able to make the build for ios4 but when i made a build for ios3.1.3 it gives me "signcode error" at the time of sync can any one suggest me the proper way of making the build for ios3.1.3 through xcode 4 . As far as i know entitlements.plist is not required in Xcode 4.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can't build app for iOS 3.* in XCode4, you can however set the deployment target of you project to iOS 3.*.

Setting the deployment target will make your app run on iOS 3.*, but you will have to make sure that you are not calling nay methods that are not available on iOS 3.*.

Also user classes introduced in iOS 4 will not work.

Comment: I have done this and have created the build but now when im syncing my  app then it is giving me the error that "the signer is not valid". What should i do with this error.

Comment: My first hit on google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857414/signer-not-valid-error

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set the deployment target to 3.* like rckoenes say.

The second, and more important is set in `your target->Build Phases tab->Link Binary With Libraries` the framework you need with weak link. This mean configure it from `Required` to `Optional`.

This can make you use it in old iOS. Now is obvious you can't use function of new iOS in the older iOS. This mean you can check like `respondToSelector` or only use function that run in your old iOS.

If you run a function that don't exist in old iOS, it will crash. But, at least, will run until it.